# How do I check if installed VLC is 64 bit or 32 bit?

Tags: architecture

How do I check if installed VLC is 64 bit or 32 bit, if I installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: NOTE: Unless overridden, the package selected by apt-get will be the same bitiness as the underlying OS if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `file` command from terminal:

```
file $(which vlc)
```

In my case the vlc version is 64-bit:

```
/usr/bin/vlc: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically
linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24,
BuildID[sha1]=63a2c2e7d5b12db4ad69cc38da86622492649af9, stripped
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can ask the packaging system what you installed:

```
$ dpkg -s vlc    
Package: vlc
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: video
Installed-Size: 3765
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1
...
```

Here, the architecture is shown to be `amd64`, or 64-bit.

---

While not a problem with `vlc`, the `file` approach can fail with the obvious program names for some packages, like `firefox`:

```
$ file $(which firefox)
/usr/bin/firefox: symbolic link to `../lib/firefox/firefox.sh'
```

You could follow the link, but then you'd be looking at a script.