# How to install VLC 64-bit version in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit, vlc, obs-studio

How to install VLC (VideoLAN) 64-bit version in Ubuntu 18 (also 64-bit)?

Already installed VLC from Ubuntu Software App and also from terminal, but don't know how to specify the 64-bit version, neither I'm sure if it exists for Linux (it exists for windows).

I need to have VLC and OBS Studio both 64-bit or 32-bit.

Also I don't know how to check the current installed version.
Tried the [solutions in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526182/how-do-i-check-if-installed-vlc-is-64-bit-or-32-bit) but don't work for me, it appears:

```
$ file $(which vlc)
/snap/bin/vlc: symbolic link to /usr/bin/snap

$ dpkg -s vlc
...package 'vlc' is not installed...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have installed VLC via snap. Snap is self contained package. It doesn't use system binaries and it is different than apt.

If you install vlc via apt, you will be able to execute command shown in solution.

Comment: Thanks, installed both VLC and OBS Studio using apt-get, and everything works now! Also I'm able to verify the installed version like you said.